# Github readme.md showing plain code instead of title for url

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to use a url but show only Title not full url.

But its not working and showing plain code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1F4l.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the case:

- in the editor section of a markdown file (if you click on preview, you would actually see a link).
  Actually complete the edit (commit your change) and check if the link is proprely displayed.
- in a `<pre></pre>` section
- in a file which is not a markdown (does not end with the `.md` extension), like a `.txt` file, which should not be your case.